# is it possible to show the hidden column of table in mysql 8

Tags: mysql

I am read the implemention of MVCC of mysql 8 that told me there contains some hidden column:

- RowID
- DB_TRX_ID
- DB_ROLL_PTR

is it possible to show the hidden column?

Comment: I don't think so. The code paths that call `get_sys_col()` internally in the InnoDB storage engine code are few, and I don't think they include querying them to view in result sets. Only to populate the columns for internal use. Why would you need to view these columns?

Comment: I just want to see the version of the rows changed in MySQL transaction to make a deepth understanding of MVCC. @BillKarwin

Comment: You might like to use Jeremy Cole's scripts for inspecting the internals of InnoDB data. https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_ruby and read his blogs about InnoDB internals if you have not already read them: https://blog.jcole.us/innodb/

Comment: Also, a `FULLTEXT` index adds another key.